# How to update Meta Tags in SSR Nuxt 2 using Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, seo, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

Title, Description and OG Tags are updated after 1 second.

When I check this with Facebook Debugger. It shows that my Page doesn't have OG tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

But, when I inspect I'm able to find all the OG tags. But I can clearly see that the Title changes in split second from default to Dynamic Values.

What's the mistake I'm making here?

Below is my code:

```
<template>
    
</template>

<script>

import axios from "axios";
import {
    ref,
    useMeta,
    defineComponent,
    useFetch
} from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";
import Header from "../components/Header"
import Footer from "../components/Footer"

    
  export default defineComponent({
  components: { 
      Header,
      Footer 
    },

        head: {},

        setup(props) {
            
            const {
                title,
                meta
            } = useMeta();

            const titleTag = ref("")
            const descriptionTag = ref("")

            const { fetch } = useFetch(async () => {

                 axios.get("https://htimyapi")
                .then(data => {
  
                    titleTag.value = data.Title
                    
                    descriptionTag.value = data.Desc
                    
                    title.value = titleTag.value;
                    meta.value = [{
                        charset: "utf-8"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "viewport",
                        content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "description",
                        name: "description",
                        content: descriptionTag.value
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "twitter:card",
                        name: "twitter:card",
                        content: descriptionTag.value
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "twitter:site",
                        name: "twitter:site",
                        content: "https://mywebsite.com"
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "twitter:url",
                        name: "twitter:url",
                        content: "https://mywebsite.com"
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "twitter:title",
                        name: "twitter:title",
                        content: titleTag.value
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "twitter:description",
                        name: "twitter:description",
                        content: descriptionTag.value
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "twitter:image",
                        name: "twitter:image",
                        content: "https://via.placeholder.com/1200x627"
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "og:site_name",
                        property: "og:site_name",
                        content: "My Website"
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "og:type",
                        property: "og:type",
                        content: descriptionTag.value
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "og:url",
                        property: "og:url",
                        content: document.location.toString()
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "og:title",
                        property: "og:title",
                        content: titleTag.value
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "og:description",
                        property: "og:description",
                        content: descriptionTag.value
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "og:image",
                        property: "og:image",
                        content: "https://via.placeholder.com/1200x627"
                    },

                    {
                        hid: "og:image:width",
                        property: "og:image:width",
                        content: "1200"
                    },
                    {
                        hid: "og:image:height",
                        property: "og:image:height",
                        content: "627"
                    }
                    ]
                
                    
                    loader.value = false


                })
                .catch(error => {

                    loader.value = false
                    if (error.response) {
                    // Request made and server responded
                    console.log(error.response.data);
                    console.log(error.response.status);
                    } else if (error.request) {
                    // The request was made but no response was received
                    console.log(error.request);
                    } else {
                    // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                    console.log('Error', error.message);
                    }
                })
            


            })

            fetch()
            
                    
    return {

      

    }
  }

})

</script>
```

Comment: try making the API call using SSR with asyncData (useAsync)

Comment: Facing a similar issue here. Did you find a solution to this?